# Rosserial connection doesn't work due to signal

Tags: rosserial, rosserial-arduino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have an arduino MEGA and I want to communicate via rosserial with my ros node.

Somewhere in my arduino code I have the following line.

```
if(intensity[n] <= myCounter) 
{
        digitalWrite((2*(n-8))+shiftSaidaInicial, LOW);
}
```

When I try to make the connection running `rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyACM0` it says that it's unnable to conenct to the device.

However, if I change the previous line to the following it syncs perfectly.

```
if(intensity[n] >= myCounter) 
{
        digitalWrite((2*(n-8))+shiftSaidaInicial, LOW);
}
```

The only thing I changed was the **<=** to **>=**. Sadly, so the code makes sense, I need the <= instead..

Anyone knows why this is happening?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261310/rosserial-connection-doesn%27t-work-due-to-signal/) by [jonagf](https://answers.ros.org/users/29777/jonagf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-05-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-08**:
I'm not an Arduino expert, but does it use pin-multiplexing for the serial and the DOUT? If so, your first version may be messing with some of the pins needed for your serial connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As @gvdhoorn mentioned, if `n == 0`, you will apply `digitalWrite()` on the pin 0 that is the serial RX pin on the Arduino MEGA and the serial communication will no longer work.

---

Originally posted by [rreignier](https://answers.ros.org/users/21983/rreignier/) with karma: 544 on 2017-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1